# Parameterized late fusion between two networks

Tags: python, keras

I would like to concatenate two networks whose outputs are similar, but whose inputs differ. The inputs are respectively Optical flow and RGB versions of the same video clips.

I already used to concatenate these two networks successfully, but I would like to use a sort of fusion parameter in order to experiment the possibilities that the global network is trained with different scales of importance given to the sub-networks.

As my networks are implemented in Keras, I don't know how to do so using these functions https://keras.io/layers/merge/

Comment: What is a fusion, what do you want to do?

Comment: @DanielMöller I want to merge the output of the Optical Flow stream with the output of the RGB stream. Flatten both of these outputs. Concatenate them before the classification layer.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a simply trainable multiply by param layer....

```
class MultiplyByTrainable(Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MultiplyByTrainable, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.kernel = self.add_weight(name='kernel', 
                                      shape=(1,),
                                      initializer='ones',
                                      trainable=True)

        #optional self.bias = self.add_weight(name='kernel', 
        #                              shape=(1,),
        #                              initializer='zeros',
        #                              trainable=True)

        self.built = True

    def call(self, inputs):
        return inputs * self.kernel # + self.bias

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return input_shape
```

And try something like:

```
out1 = MultiplyByTrainable(name='net_mult_1')(net1_output)
out2 = MultiplyByTrainable(name='net_mult_2')(net2_output)
outputs = Add()([out1, out2]) #or Concatenate()([out1, out2])
```

---

Or you can just use a very basic lambda layer:

```
w1 = someWeight
w2 = 1 - w1
out = Lambda(lambda x: w1 * x[0] + w2 * x[1])([net1_output, net2_output])
```